# .htaccess rewriting and GET parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my redirections.

Basically, I get the name of the page using a page GET variable, like this: 
`index.php?page=page1`, which I want to be accessed by `page1.html`

Then, if there are other get variables, I just want to append them, like this:
`page1.html?var1=value1` points to `index.php?page=page1&var1=value1`

I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.html$  index.php?page=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.html\?(.*)$  index.php?page=$1&$2  [L]
```

And I never seem to get any other get parameter than the page variable...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Query String Append](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag.

Per the docs:

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.

Update your rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+).html$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```